# react-native-vision-camera sending undefined device.id value

Tags: android, react-native

Below is my code for a home page aka just trying to follow the setup instructions for the react-native-vision-camera library. When I run my app on an Android device it throws an error saying "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'device.id')". I am not sure how to fix this or what could be the issue. My Android emulator is Pixel 3a XL API 30.

```
const Home = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation();
const devices = useCameraDevices();
const device = devices.back;

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home Page</Text>
        <Button title="Home" onPress={() => navigation.push("landing")} />
        <Camera
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
            device={device}
        />
    </View>
);
```

};

Answer (score 14, accepted):

my friend!

Before rendering the camera component, you need to check if the device is not null.

Example:

```html
  if (device == null) {
    return <ActivityIndicator size={20} color={'red'} />;
  }

  return (
    <Camera
      ref={refCamera}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      device={device}
      isActive={true}
      frameProcessorFps={'auto'}
      frameProcessor={frameProcessor}
    />
  );
```

Comment: I am getting null in device

any clue how to fix it?

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: @OsmanKhalid Did you fix the error. I am also getting the same. It would be helpful if you post your answer.

Comment: @ElangovanEaaswaramurty. I think this library has an error, so I could not fix it, but I used a different library and that is serving the purpose. Here is the code: https://github.com/Hassan1305/CameraApplication.git